# Why should an object have a method returning "this"?

Tags: java, oop, jodatime

I recently stumbled upon an odd detail in the Java JodaTime Library.

There is a class `Instant` which has a method called `toInstant()`. The method simply returns `this`.

```
/**
 * Get this object as an Instant by returning <code>this</code>.
 * 
 * @return <code>this</code>
 */
public Instant toInstant() {
    return this;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how this should be helpful. If you want to call this method you would already need the object you hope to get from it. Or is this simply there for satisfying an interface?

Comment: Yes, `toInstant()` should be implemented because it is defined in interface `ReadableInstant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instant` extends `AbstractInstant` which implements `ReadableInstant`.

`DateTime` and other time objects also are `ReadableInstant`, so yes, this is satisfying an interface; and, the part you are looking at might not make as much sense in that context.  Looking at the other implementations of `ReadableInstant`, it makes more sense.

For example

```
MutableDateTime dateTime = new MutableDateTime();
// Available because MutableDateTime is a ReadableInstant
Instant instant = dateTime.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 1):

imagine different methods doing stuff and returning this. You could:

```
x.doStuff().andStuff().andStuff(2).otherStuff().OtherStuffToo();
```

Answer (score 1):

if i have `MyInstant extends Instant` then i could return it as the superclass

Answer (score 1):

Returning this allows for [FluentInterfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) as described my martin fowler.